# My goodness! (Why native speakers say this phrase?)

Tags: exclamatives

> My goodness!

Why this expression is used as an exclamation expression? I can't understand it.

goodness: the quality or state of being good

Comment: I am sure your language has similar expressions.

Comment: It's a [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) (though speakers may not be aware today that that is its origin).

Comment: @ColinFine: You are so smart of it and it's so smart of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to wikitionary, it is a euphemistic form of "My God." "Good" and "God" have similar phonemes, and, in orthodox versions of Christianity, God is the embodiment of goodness.

Comment: There are some people who consider saying the word *God* to be *taking the lord's name in vain.*  So using *goodness* reduces the possibility of damnation.

Comment: Yes. I realized after I posted  my answer that it implied a further question. I decided not to trot out my quite limited knowledge of theology. But thank you for finishing my post off so competently.